# Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt iterations) on netcoreapp2.1

Tags: asp.net-core

System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes

function seems it is not available on netcoreapp2.1, when I run my web app I receive the following error when I call the function using the DeriveBytes procedure:

```
Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core
```

I have already tried installing some nuget packages to fix the problem, but seems no one include the required function

The function needs to be exactly the same, or alternatively a function that could derive the same bytes from same parameters.

The current function is not loaded, I need it without any changes in derived bytes

Comment: This is not a method but a Class please see documentation: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8), the method you refer to is a constructor of the class. This has also been supported in .Net Core since .Net Core 1.0

Comment: I tried change the target framework from netstandard2.0 to netcoreapp2.1 without success

Comment: Please post the code which is causing this error to appear.